# Hyperlinks created by VBA truncating

Tags: excel, vba

The below is part of my code on a protected sheet to unprotect the sheet, create a folder, make a hyperlink to it, open the folder and reprotect the sheet.

This works fine until I save the spreadsheet - it then truncates all the links to `..\..\..\..\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences...` instead of `\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences...`, rendering them all invalid. Can anyone help?

```
If .Value = "TTRO - Emergency" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" And Cells(i, 14) <> "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Licence19"
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 4), Address:="\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\TTRO\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", TextToDisplay:=.Value
         dirName = Cells(4, i).Values
         MkDir ("\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\TTRO\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")
         Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\TTRO\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", vbNormalFocus)
         ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Licence19", AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by the setting "***Update links on save***" since this happens when you save the workbook.

In Excel, try the following:

1. Go to **File** >> **Options** >> **Advanced**
2. Find the section **General** (almost at the bottom)
3. Click the button **Web Options**
4. Go to the tab **Files**
5. Uncheck the box **Update links on save**

Answer (score 1):

When storing the Workbook, Excel will translate all Hyperlink paths to relative paths if possible. *Relative* means relative to the *Hyperlink Base*. Per default, this *Hyperlink Base* is the path of the workbook.

So if your workbook is `C:\test\wb1.xlsx` and your hyperlink points to `C:\test\subtest\testfile.txt`, after storing the workbook, the hyperlink will change to `.\subtest\testfile.txt`. Would be handy if you move the whole folder `C:\test` to a different location, but not if you move only the workbook (or send it to someone else).

To prevent this, you can change the *Hyperlink Base* to something "impossible". The setting can be found in Excel unter File->Info on the right side of the screen (under Properties). You can change it there, or you can change it via VBA using the `BuiltinDocumentProperties`:

```
activeworkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Hyperlink Base") = "ABC"
```

Now, when saving the workbook, it will check if the hyperlinks are relative to the path `"ABC"` and, as they are not, will store them unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer not messing up with settings like I do, simply store the full path to ScreenTip.

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add targetCell, path, ScreenTip:=path
```

When needing to call the original path, use the same attribute:

```
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).ScreenTip
```

That's it!